# What is the iOS equivalent of PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber android function?

Tags: ios, phone-number, libphonenumber

Is their any equivalent of `PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber` (Format the phone number only) and `PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumberToE164` (Formats the specified phoneNumber to the E.164 representation.) on iOS ?

My goal is to format a phone numbers to int64 (to store them in database as int64) and also format int64 phone numbers when show to end user

Comment: There is nothing in-built. I have used [PhoneNumberKit](https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit) successfully

Comment: but is their already any compiled library available of phoneNumberKit ?

Comment: No, it is open source so you simply include the framework into your project using Cocoapods or Carthage. Providing a binary distribution would be more work for the author and less flexible for the user (you wouldn't be able to debug inside the framework for example)

Comment: but unfortunately i m on Delphi, and i can import only with compiled library :(

Comment: Then you will need to compile the library yourself using Xcode and then add the compiled framework to your project.  It is very rare for open source projects to provide compiled frameworks.